# ViewPager2 dependency confusion

Tags: android, androidx, android-viewpager2

I was about to try [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) but I don't understand when I saw someone add the following dependency declaration in their gradle file:

```
implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
```

I am using AndroidX and, even without adding this in my app-level gradle file, I still have access to the [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) class and I am able to add it in my code. Is this line only needed when a project is still using legacy Android support libraries and you just want to use a specific AndroidX component such as ViewPager2?

Answer (score 1):

If you have visibility of the `ViewPager2` classes in your project without adding an explicit dependency on the `androidx.viewpager2:viewpager` library, then you have a transitive dependency on the `androidx.viewpager2:viewpager` library. As in, one of the libraries which you have an explicit dependency on has a dependency on the `androidx.viewpager2:viewpager` library.

You can run the `dependencies` Gradle task to see your application's dependency graph and to work out from it which of your explicit dependencies is bringing in the `androidx.viewpager2:viewpager` library. In my project, when I run the `gradle :app:dependencies` task, I see in the dependency graph that it is my app's dependency on `com.google.android.material:material` which brings in the `androidx.viewpager2:viewpager` library.

If you prefer, you can run the `dependencyInsight` Gradle task instead to get a more direct answer to the question. For example, in my project, if I run `gradle :app:dependencyInsight --configuration debugCompileClasspath --dependency viewpager2`, then I see output as follows:

```bash
androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0
\--- com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0
     \--- debugCompileClasspath
```

Answer (score 0):

**To use ViewPager2, add the following AndroidX dependency to your project's build.gradle file:**

`dependencies { implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0" }`